# Android NDK library is not loading on runtime for samsung galaxy 4.0.2 phones only

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I am trying to test my NDK programming on different phones. The same app runs on all other phones but on samsung 4.0.2 it just stops , throwing the below error. Am i missing any thing ? any help is appreciated

```
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4486)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 **10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]:   161 cannot locate '__aeabi_idiv0'...**
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
   10-29 12:02:57.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
```

Comment: restarting the phone didn't help :\ ?

Comment: Nopes :( I tried on two different samsung S1 phones before posting here .. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known bug on Android 4.0 with native libraries loading which may be the cause of your problem. I wrote a [detailed blogpost](https://moodstocks.com/blog/article/ice-cream-sandwich-why-native-code-support-sucks/) on it if you want to dive into the details. Long story short:

I guess the library you're trying to use is compiled for different architectures (generally armeabi and armeabi-v7a, respectively stored in `libs/armeabi` and `libs/armeabi-v7a`). On Android 4.0, the `System.loadLibrary()` method is messed up: when you try to load library `libsomething.so`, instead of searching for the native library in the folder corresponding to the architecture of the device, it loads the first library with name `libsomething.so` it finds in any `libs` subfolder, potentially loading the wrong architecture, which can cause such a crash.

The simplest workaround:

- Give different names to the libraries depending on their architecture, for example `libsomething.so` for armeabi and `libsomething-v7a.so` for armeabi-v7a. That way, when using `System.loadLibrary()`, it can't get confused by the fact that several files have the same name.
- Once this is done, the problem is that you must know which one of these two filenames to load with `System.loadLibrary()`, *i.e.* you must detect the architecture used by the device by yourself. There are several ways to do that: one of them is to use the `android_getCpuFeatures()` from the `cpu-features.h` file from native code (explained in the above blogpost), another is to parse the system `/proc/cpuinfo` file from Java (for example as explained [here](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/))

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want to do a first quick and easy check: remove the subfolders in `libs` that don't fit the architecture of your device (I see you talk about a Galaxy S1, which is armeabi-v7a), and run your code as it is right now. If it works, you'll have a good probability that this is actually the issue!

Comment: @mbrenon I am facing the same thing here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931392/run-time-error-in-native-android?noredirect=1#comment35010792_22931392` can you please guide me where i am doing wrong !! as i tried the way you suggest in comment