# Video Thumbnailer App Android Issues

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-file, video-thumbnails

I have a problem with an Android App I've wrote.

The app just accesses the media store(of device) using specific folders and creates thumbnails of the videos that are included in these folders, then it goes ahead and lists these thumbnails in a ListView.

When I install the app on a gingerbread or Jelly bean device I have no issues at all. But when i install the app in a device that is running Ice Cream (Api 15) the app breaks. From the logcat I can see that the app is picking the filename and the foldername.

Have a look at my logcat, and please let me know of any ideas or if you have ever came accross that error before :

The link for the logcat is [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvUHS.png)

Comment: The only related thing I found is the NDK 8c [release notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html): _"Removed the following symbols, introduced in GCC 4.6 libgcc.a, from the X86 platform libc.so library: __aeabi_idiv0, __aeabi_ldiv0, __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1, and __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr2."_

Comment: Hello Marton, what is that supposed to mean? Is there something I have to change.?

Comment: I don't really know whether that means anything for you. But I've found [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667291/android-ndk-library-is-not-loading-on-runtime-for-samsung-galaxy-4-0-2-phones-on) that might be related if you are using native libraries on multiple architectures:

Comment: I will have alook! Thank you for your help ;)